# HTML5 + javascript: how to make a sprite stay in the middle of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, scroll

I'm trying to draw a sprite in the middle of the screen in a HTML5/JS application. I have a large background image (larger than the screen) and I need to scroll through it but the sprite must always be drawn at the center of the current view. So I created a div with the background and I'm trying to draw the sprite but when I try to handle the scroll event the draw does not happens.

One thing I did was that I set up the canvas size to the size of the image (very large). Is this correct? How can I setup this properly?

Thank you.

Here is my Code:

```js
var bgCanvas, bgCanvasContext;
var carImg;
var cineImg;

var dstXRightLane = 547;
var dstXLeftLane = 450;

var maxPoints = 1499999;
var currentPoints = 500000;

var firstPrizeHeigth = 17430;
var firstPrizeDstX = 150;
var firstPrizeDstY = 16800;

function getHeightFromPoints( points )
{
    var height = 0;
    console.log( "points is ", points );    
    height = Math.round(18897 - 0.012598 * points);
    console.log( "height is ", height );    
    
    return height;
}

function drawSprite(ctx, img, dstX, dstY)
{
    console.log("about to draw sprite...");    
    ctx.drawImage(img, dstX, dstY);
    console.log("draw returned...");         
}

function drawCar( dstX, dstY )
{
    drawSprite( bgCanvasContext, carImg, dstX, dstY );
}

function drawCarOnLeftLane( dstY )
{
    drawCar( dstXLeftLane, dstY );    
}

function drawCarOnRightLane( dstY )
{
    drawCar( dstXRightLane, dstY );
}

function gotoBotton()
{
    // cross browser solution
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight ||
                        document.documentElement.scrollHeight);    
}

var lastScrollYPosition = 0;

function scrollEventHandler(e)
{
    console.log( "handling scroll event..");
    lastScrollYPosition = window.scrollY;
    
    console.log( "current scroll y-position is ", lastScrollYPosition );
    console.log( "current scroll top is ", window.scrollTop );
    console.log( "current scroll bottom is ", window.scrollBotton );    
    
    console.log( "scroll event handler finished" );    
}

function isToWinPrize( currentHeight, prizeHeight )
{
    return( currentHeight < prizeHeight );
}


// on load function 
(function()
{   
    var dstY = 18430;    

    console.log("main program entry point");
    
    console.log("about to call gotoBotton");
    gotoBotton();    
    console.log("gotoBotton returned");
    
    bgCanvas = document.getElementById("bgPrizes");
    bgCanvas.width = 1080;
    bgCanvas.height = 18898;    
    bgCanvasContext = bgCanvas.getContext("2d");    
    carImg = document.getElementById("car");
    cineImg = document.getElementById("cine");     
    
    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', scrollEventHandler );
    
    currentPointsHeight = getHeightFromPoints( currentPoints );

    if( isToWinPrize(currentPointsHeight, firstPrizeHeigth) )
    {
        console.log("drawing prize..." );
        drawSprite( bgCanvasContext, cineImg, firstPrizeDstX, firstPrizeDstY );
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("still need ", firstPrizeHeigth - currentPointsHeight, " points to win" );
    }    
 
    drawCarOnLeftLane( dstY );
    drawCarOnRightLane( dstY );
    
} ());
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Progress Bar</title>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <div style="background-image: url(./img/bg.jpg); height: 18898px; 
                                                            width: 1080px;">
            <canvas id="bgPrizes"></canvas>
            
            <div style="display:none">
                <img id="car" src="./img/car.png" width="82" height="162">
            </div>
            <div style="display:none">
                <img id="cine" src="./img/cine.png" width="199" height="262">
            </div>
            
            <script src="progressBar.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like game, the character at the middle and the background move, make it like moving.

You should make a 1920*1080 one, put sprite at the middle and move the background, I think this solution may suit for you.